# Detect a mouse click within a specific NSCollectionView

Tags: xcode, macos, mouseevent, nscollectionview

I am looking for an answer to detect a mouse click within a NSCollectionView. So when there is a click in the NSCollectionView, I can let it do some stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `NSCollectionView` and implement `- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent*)event`